# Reverse lookup on a Django asymmetric 1:N relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

In Django, what is the query manager associated for reverse lookup of a 1:N relationship?

Let's say I have a simple Django model:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and a few objects defined as follows:

```
a = Entity.objects.create(name="A", score=5)
b = Entity.objects.create(name="B", score=10, parent=a)
c = Entity.objects.create(name="C", score=11, parent=a)
```

If I want to find out all entities that have a score of less than 10, or any entities that have a parent whose score is less than 10, it is easy:

```
Entity.objects.filter(Q(score < 5) | Q(parent__score < 5))
```

The above will match exactly one entity, "a", as expected. However, if I want to know all top-level (parent == None) entities whose score is more than 10, or who have children whose score is more than 10, how do I define the query?

```
Entity.objects.filter(parent=None).(Q(score > 10) | Q(?__score > 10))
```

I need the matched answer to be the parent, not the child (and I need a queryset so I can refine it as needed). And if I exclude the non-parent entities then I cannot figure out the query to write. What should I write in place of the **?** above so that the query returns one entry, "a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`related_query_name` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) is the name which is used for the reverse filter name for a model. The default for `related_query_name` is the name of the model itself in lowercase, unless you specify `related_name` then it defaults to that. Hence in your filters you can use `entity` to access the related child. Furthermore the example queries you give will raise an error because `Q(score < 5)` is **not** how you make less than queries, you need to use `__lt` instead. Considering all this your query should be of the form:

```
Entity.objects.filter(Q(score__gt=10) | Q(entity__score__gt=10), parent=None)
```

Better yet set a `related_name` and `related_query_name` on your foreign key to make more sense:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="children", related_query_name="child")
```

Now you can write your query as:

```
Entity.objects.filter(Q(score__gt=10) | Q(child__score__gt=10), parent=None)
```